# Suddenly: NameError: name 'HTTPServer' is not defined, while everything was working well

Tags: python

I have a program (PyCharm 2023.1) which installs an HTTPServer on port 8082. It was working very well until suddenly, running it, I got "NameError: name 'HTTPServer' is not defined". Besides, if I try to run it with debugger I also get a second error "Connection to Python debugger failed. Socket closed".

I didn't make any changes to the program, so expected it to run as usual...

I also created a simple program (the one you get with File->New Project, which have no imports and only prints "Hi PyCharms") and running it I get same errors (?!). Some general information/variables got damaged?

Do you have any idea of what happened and how to get rid of these errors?

Thank you all in advance.
Regards, Livio.

Comment: What module were you importing `HTTPServer` from?  Sounds like you've created a `.py` file with the same name, that is shadowing the actual module - but does not contain a definition for `HTTPServer`.

Comment: Ops, after hours I found the problem: while looking at the server.py file I inadvertently changed the name of the definition of HHTPServer class (copy/paste? Don't really know) and so...

Comment: You might want to consider using a version control system to keep track of changes you make to your code.